# SQL: Group by only consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with a million rows and 50+columns, in which I have kept all record changes. Because of the very large table size, a column needs to be deleted and all subsequently duplicate records need to be deleted.

```
ID   otherID   a     b   |    c  
----------------------------------------
1     10       1     2   |    1
2     10       1     2   |    2
3     20       2     2   |    3
4     10       1     2   |    4
5     10       10    2   |    5
6     10       10    2   |    6
7     10       1     2   |    7
```

So, lets say that I'm deleting column `C`, and I need to keep only the 1st unique record. The records that I need are 1, 3, 5, and 7. So my question is how do I group by 1 and 2 and 4, but not row 6?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sql server managemnt studio

Comment: With that sample data, what's the expected result?

Comment: Rows number 1,3,5 and 7

Comment: @Jove_v: I realize this is an old question, but I'm hoping you'll help clarify something. Wouldn't you want to keep rows 1, 3, 4, 5, and 7, while removing rows 2 and 6? Thus grouping {1, 2,}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}? That's what your question and data seem to suggest, but your summary at the end was a bit confusing regarding how 4 and 6 should be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got this right, for the data:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (
  ID INT, 
  otherID INT, 
  a INT, 
  b INT
);

INSERT 
INTO @T (
  ID,
  otherID, 
  a, 
  b
)
VALUES
  (1, 10, 1, 2),
  (2, 10, 1, 2),
  (3, 20, 2, 2),
  (4, 10, 1, 2),
  (5, 10, 10, 2),
  (6, 10, 10, 2),
  (7, 10, 1, 2)
;
```

The following query should return what you're looking for:

```
WITH grp AS (
  SELECT        ID,
                otherID,  
                a,  
                b,
                grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY otherID ORDER BY (id))
               - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY otherID, a, b ORDER BY (id))
   FROM        @T
), 
filter AS (
  SELECT       ID, 
               otherID,  
               a, 
               b,
               grp,
               rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp, otherID, a, b ORDER BY (id))
  FROM         grp
)

DELETE
FROM           filter 
WHERE          rn >1;

SELECT         * 
FROM           @T 
ORDER BY       id
```

This returns:

```
ID   otherID   a     b   
-------------------------
1    10        1     2
3    20        2     2
5    10        10    2
7    10        1     2
```

You can see this in action in at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/586b3/2/1).

Comment: I really like this approach, and it's one of the most elegant I've found from a lot of Stack Overflow answers. I'm confused by one aspect of the results, however. This doesn't return record #4. That's consistent with the OP's request. But _shouldn't_ it be returned since it's not a _consecutive_ duplicate? I.e., isn't it analogous to record #7, which also has the same values, but is not consecutive? I suspect I'm missing something here, and am hoping you might clarify. (FWIW: I was confused by the OP didn't include #4 in their request as well.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney, derived from the sample data OP provided my guess is `otherID` plays a somewhat special role. If you drop it from `grp` expression you'll get record#4 in the result set too.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4108b1f87e743a0a7ac824570cd08c93

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difference of `row_number()`s approach:

```
select min(Id), otherId, a, b
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) - 
              row_number() over (partition by otherId, a, b order by id)
             ) as grp
     ) t
group by otherId, a, b, grp;
```

For rows with the same values in adjacent rows, the different of rows number is constant.

Comment: i just edited my question ...will this answer still work ?? 
 see the part about rows number 1,2 and 4

Answer (score 0):

U can get 1, 3 and 5 th row using the following query

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT tbl.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY otherId, a, b ORDER BY id)
             AS rn
             FROM [tablename] tbl
     ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

But the requirement of getting 7th row isn't clear as its not the unique row (its same as 1,2,4 th row